# Luxon fromFormat pattern ignore time

Tags: javascript, momentjs, luxon

When I try to create Date object from string format in Luxon I get invalid date.

**Hours and minutes are not passed**. This gives me an Invalid date

```
const dateString = '28.09.2022';
DateTime.fromFormat(dateString, 'dd.LL.yyyy HH:mm').toJSDate();
// Invalid date
```

**Using moment library** it seems that if hours and minutes are not passed it defaults to 00:00:00

```
const dateString = '28.09.2022';
moment(date, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm').toDate();
// Wed Sep 28 2022 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)
```

Is there some option to format both formats with hours and without in Luxon using one method as I was using moment in many places and it accepted 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm' format no matter if you pass HH:mm in string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I fear that there is no native way to get [`moment(String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) behaviour in Luxon. Moreover, it seems that there is no counterpart of [`moment(String, String[])`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/) in Luxon.

Please note that, while *"Moment's parser is very forgiving"*, Luxon [Parsing](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/parsing?id=consider-alternatives) section of the docs states that *"Luxon is quite strict about the format matching the string exactly."*

You can build your own custom method and implement the business logic you need, here a possible example:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

const customParse = (dateString) => {
  let dt = DateTime.fromFormat(dateString, 'dd.LL.yyyy');
  if (dt.isValid) {
    return dt;
  }
  return DateTime.fromFormat(dateString, 'dd.LL.yyyy HH:mm');
}

let dateString = '28.09.2022';
console.log(customParse(dateString).toJSDate());
dateString = '28.09.2022 11:46';
console.log(customParse(dateString).toJSDate());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@3.0.4/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```